# Websocket - Sink.actorRefWithAck and Source.queue - only one request TO server gets processed?

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, akka, scala.js

Consider this

```
 def handle = WebSocket.accept[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]
 {
     request =>
        log.info("Handling byte-message")
        ActorFlow.actorRef
        {
          out => MyActor.props(out)
        }
  }
```

Whenever a byte message is sent to the websocket, it gets delegated to the actor and before I get a log entry.

Works fine.

Now the same logic, with a Flow instead

```
def handle = WebSocket.accept[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]
{
     request =>
      {
        log.info("Handling byte-message")
        Flow.fromSinkAndSource(sink, source).log("flow")
      }
}
```

I'll add the rest of the code:

```
 val tickingSource: Source[Array[Byte], Cancellable] =
    Source.tick(initialDelay = 1 second, interval = 10 seconds, tick = NotUsed)
      .map(_ => Wrapper().withKeepAlive(KeepAlive()).toByteArray)

  val myActor = system.actorOf(Props{new MyActor(null)}, "myActor")

  val serverMessageSource = Source
    .queue[Array[Byte]](10, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
    .mapMaterializedValue { queue => myActor ! InitTunnel(queue)}

  val sink = Sink.actorRefWithAck(myActor, InternalMessages.Init(), InternalMessages.Acknowledged(), InternalMessages.Completed())

  val source = tickingSource.merge(serverMessageSource)
```

It has a keepAlive source, and an actual source, if the server wants to push something, merged.

The sink is again the actor.

Now the problem is, in this scenario I get **EXACTLY** one message from the client TO the server, even if it sends more, they do not get passed to `myActor`

At first I thought this may be due to the `null` reference passed to `myActor` here, but then the first one could not be processed either. I am out of ideas, what is causing this. The flow itself works, I get the keepAlive messages just fine and if I refresh the client (Scala.js) again, first request gets sent just fine to the server and server responds and all is well

**edit to clarify:**

I am **NOT** talking about the log entry here - I am sorry, I had another log entry in `myActor` and got myself confused.

If the client sends more than one message the server does not handle it. It never reaches the actor, although the client definitely sends it :(

What I would expect:

1) At first message from client to server, the websocket gets created
2) The websocket is kept alive by the server, via the `tickingSource` (that actually works!)
3) If the client sends another request, it gets handled by `myActor` and that also responds to the client over the websocket

So, 3) does not work. In fact, the client sends a message, but that never reaches `myActor` after the initial one :(

edit:

This is my actor logic for initializing the websocket/stream in `myActor`:

```
var tunnel: Option[SourceQueueWithComplete[Array[Byte]]] = None

override def receive: Receive = {
   case i: InternalMessages.InitTunnel =>
      log.info("Initializing tunnel")
      tunnel = Some(i.sourceQueue)

    case _: InternalMessages.Init =>
      sender() ! InternalMessages.Acknowledged()
      log.info("websocket stream initialized")

    case _: InternalMessages.Completed =>
      log.info("websocket stream completed")

    case q: Question => {
        tunnel match {
           case Some(t) => t offer Answer()...
           case None => log.error("No tunnel available")
        }
    }
}


object InternalMessages {
  case class Acknowledged()
  case class Init()
  case class Completed()
  case class InitTunnel(sourceQueue: SourceQueueWithComplete[Array[Byte]])
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect, but it is normal that you only get one log entry. The `log.info("Handling byte-message")` statement is executed only once, when the websocket connection is established. If you open a new connection, you should get another log entry. If you send more messages inside the same websocket, you should not expect more log entries as the function you pass to `WebSocket.accept` is only called when establishing a websocket connection.

Comment: @FredericA. Not talking about the log entry here. If the client sends more than one message the server does not handle it. It never reaches the actor :(

Comment: You are using `Sink.actorRefWithAck` are you sure that your actor sends the expected `ackMessage`?

Comment: @FredericA. I added the code. For me it looks like it, am I missing something here?

Comment: Shouldn't something transform incoming byte arrays into your `Question` type? edit: Turned the rest of this comment into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the feeling that you don't send acks after receiving the `Question` message, but you should as the akka docs says (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html#sink-actorrefwithack): `It also requires the given acknowledgement message after each stream element to make back-pressure work.`

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem in Java. But messages were not sent to the "actorRefWithAck" at all(just onInitMessage was received). The actor was remote and was sending "Acknowledged" message that was not the same instance as in Sink.actorRefWithAck() method. Adding equals method to the message resolved the issue.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj.getClass().equals(getClass());
}
```

Comment: As the ack-message has to be _identical_ to the ack-message defined on the method call to `actorRefWith` the ack-message shall rather be an `enum Ack {INSTANCE}` instead of a class.You have acheived this by implementing equals as test of class equality.